# Interaction plot for regression analysis with moderator variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the interaction plot for my regression analysis.
I already tested the regression. It's fine.
Here's the code:

```
plot(data$ocs, data$efs, pch=19)
abline(lm(data$efs~data$ocs))

model1 <- lm(efs ~ ocs * rws, data = data)
summary(model1)
interact_plot(model=model1, pred = ocs, modx = rws, data = data)
```

Now everything works except interact_plot. I get back following error message:

```
Error in element_line(colour = text_and_line_color, linewidth = 0.5, linetype = 1,  : 
  unused argument (linewidth = 0.5)
```

What does this even mean?

interact_plot is a function from interactions!

```
rws = c(3.8, 3.8, 4.4, 3.2, 4, 3.8, 4.2, 4.6, 4.4, 3, 3.6, 3.4, 3.8, 4, 3.4, 
4, 2.2, 4, 3.4, 4, 2.8, 3, 3, 4.2, 3, 3.6, 3.8, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 
3.4, 3.2, 3.4, 3.4, 3.8, 4, 3.2, 3, 4.6, 4, 3.4, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 
3.8, 3.6, 2.8, 3.8, 4.6, 3, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.8, 2.4, 2.4, 4.2, 
3.6, 2.6, 3.6, 2.4, 3.2, 4, 4.2, 3.4, 3.2, 3.8, 4.8, 3.6, 4, 
3, 3.4, 4.2, 4.4, 3.8, 4.2, 4, 3.6, 4.4, 4, 3, 4.6, 4.4, 4, 3.4, 
4, 3.8, 4.8, 3.4, 3.4, 3.8, 3.8, 3.6, 3.6, 4.6, 3.6, 3.6, 2.6, 
2.8, 4.6, 4, 3.4, 3.8, 3.8, 3.6, 3, 3.2, 2.8, 3.6, 3.6, 3.4, 
3.6, 2.2, 4.2, 3.6, 3.8, 3.4, 3.8, 4.4, 2.4, 2, 3.4, 4.2, 3.2, 
3.2, 3.2, 3, 3.6, 3.6, 2.8, 3.6, 2.8, 3.6, 4.4, 3, 3.6, 3.2, 
4.8, 3.4, 3.8, 4.2, 3.2, 3.6, 3.8, 3.6, 3, 4, 3.8, 3.8, 4.2, 
3.6, 4.4, 3.6, 3.4, 3.8, 4.4, 3.4, 3.4, 4, 4.2, 3.8, 3.6, 4, 
4.6, 3.2, 4, 3.4, 3, 3.2, 3.8, 3.4, 3.4, 3, 4.8, 2.8, 3.6, 3, 
4, 3.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.4, 3.8, 3.2, 4.2, 3.2, 3.6, 3.4, 4.2, 3.8, 
3.6, 4, 3.6, 3.4, 2.4, 4, 3.4, 3.6, 4, 3.4, 3.6, 3, 3.6, 3.6, 
2.4, 3.6, 1, 3.6, 4.2, 3.2, 2.6, 3.8, 3.6, 3.6, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 
3.6, 3, 4, 4, 3.2, 4.4, 3.4, 4.4, 3, 3.8, 3.6, 3.2, 3, 4.6, 4.8, 
3, 4.2, 3, 3.4, 4, 3.2, 3.2, 4.2, 4.2, 3, 2.6, 2.8, 2.2, 3.8, 
2.8, 3.8, 1.4, 3.8, 4.6, 3.8, 3.6, 4.2, 3.6, 3.4, 2.6, 3.8, 3.8, 
3.8, 2.8, 3.8, 4.8, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 4, 3.4, 3.6, 3.2, 2.6, 3.2, 
4, 3.4, 3.2, 4, 3, 4, 3.6, 3.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.4, 4.6, 3.4, 3.4, 
3.4, 4.2, 2.8, 2.4)

efs = c(3.5, 3.75, 4, 3.75, 4.25, 3.5, 4.5, 2.5, 4.25, 2, 2.5, 3, 4.5, 
2.25, 3.5, 3.5, 1.75, 4, 3, 2.75, 3.75, 3.5, 3.5, 2.25, 3, 2.25, 
3.25, 2.5, 3.75, 2, 3.5, 2.75, 4.25, 3.5, 4, 2.5, 3, 4.5, 2.5, 
3.75, 1.25, 3.75, 2.25, 3.25, 3, 4.75, 3.25, 5, 3.75, 3.5, 2.75, 
3.75, 3.75, 3.25, 4, 2.75, 4.75, 2, 3.5, 3.5, 2.75, 1.75, 1.75, 
3, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 2.25, 2.5, 2.25, 3.25, 3.75, 3, 4.25, 3.75, 4, 
4.5, 3.75, 3.75, 4.25, 3.5, 3, 3, 2.75, 4, 3, 4.25, 3.25, 3.25, 
3, 3.25, 2, 3.75, 2.5, 3.5, 4, 4, 3.25, 4.25, 4.75, 4, 4, 4.75, 
3.75, 4, 4, 4, 3.5, 3.25, 4.25, 4.5, 3.75, 4, 4.5, 3.5, 2.75, 
4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4.5, 2.75, 4.25, 3.5, 4, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 4.25, 
5, 4.75, 3.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3.5, 4, 2.75, 3.25, 3, 3, 3.75, 4, 
3.75, 2.5, 3.75, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.75, 3.25, 2.75, 3, 
3.5, 3, 4.25, 3, 3.25, 2.75, 4.75, 2.25, 4, 3.75, 3.75, 4.75, 
3.25, 4, 3.75, 3.5, 3.75, 4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 3.75, 4, 3, 2.5, 
4.25, 3.25, 4.25, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 3.25, 2.75, 
3.25, 4.25, 3, 3.25, 3, 3.75, 2.5, 2.75, 3.5, 3.5, 3.75, 4.75, 
3.5, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 4, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 3.25, 3.5, 3.25, 4.25, 
4.5, 3, 3, 4.75, 3, 3, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.25, 4.25, 4.25, 3.5, 
4, 2.25, 4.5, 3.75, 4, 4, 3, 3.75, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.25, 
3.75, 4.25, 3.5, 2.75, 4, 3.25, 2.5, 4, 2.75, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 2.75, 
4.5, 3.25, 3.25, 3.75, 3.75, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.75, 3.5, 3.5, 3.75, 
4.5, 3, 3.25, 3.75, 4.5, 3.5, 3, 3.75, 4, 3.75, 4, 3.75, 3.75, 
3, 3.75, 3.25, 4.5, 2.25, 3.25, 4, 3.75, 3.5, 2.75, 3.75)

ocs = c(2.8, 3.2, 3.4, 2, 2.6, 2.4, 2.6, 2.2, 3.6, 2.4, 2.2, 3.4, 2.8, 
1.4, 2.8, 2, 1.8, 2.8, 2.6, 2.6, 2.8, 2.6, 3.6, 1.4, 2.8, 1.8, 
2.6, 1.8, 3, 2, 2.6, 2.2, 3.6, 2.8, 3, 1.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.8, 
2.6, 2.6, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 4.4, 3.2, 4.4, 3.8, 3.4, 2.8, 2.6, 2.6, 
2.6, 2.8, 1.8, 4, 3.4, 2.6, 3.2, 2.8, 1.8, 1.2, 2, 2.4, 3.4, 
2.2, 1.6, 2.6, 1.8, 2.4, 3.2, 2.6, 2.8, 2.8, 2.4, 3.2, 2.6, 2.8, 
3.2, 3.4, 1.4, 1.6, 2, 3.2, 2.8, 3.6, 4, 2, 1.6, 2.8, 1.6, 2.6, 
2.6, 3.4, 2.8, 3.4, 2.6, 3.4, 3, 3.8, 3, 4, 3.2, 3.4, 3.2, 4.4, 
2.8, 3.2, 3.4, 4, 2, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.2, 3.4, 2.2, 3, 2.4, 3, 
3.2, 2, 1.8, 3, 2.2, 3.4, 3.6, 3.6, 3.2, 4.2, 3.6, 3, 2.6, 2.4, 
3.6, 4.2, 1.6, 3.4, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 4, 2.2, 2.8, 3.4, 1.8, 3.4, 
2, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3, 3.4, 3.6, 1.6, 1.8, 4, 
2.4, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 3.6, 3, 3.8, 2.6, 3, 3.2, 4.6, 3.8, 2.8, 
2.6, 3.8, 2.2, 2.8, 3.2, 3.4, 3.4, 2.6, 1.4, 2.4, 2.8, 3.4, 2.6, 
2.8, 2.4, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3, 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3, 3.6, 
4, 2.6, 3.2, 4, 2.8, 0, 3, 3.2, 3, 3.4, 3.2, 2.4, 2.2, 3, 3, 
3.6, 2.6, 2.8, 3.6, 2.4, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 1.8, 3.2, 2.6, 3.4, 
3, 2.2, 4, 3, 3.6, 4.2, 1.8, 2.8, 2.4, 1.8, 3.4, 3.4, 3.8, 2.6, 
3.6, 2.4, 2, 3.4, 3.4, 0, 2.8, 2.4, 1.4, 2.8, 2.2, 2.4, 3.4, 
3.2, 1.8, 2, 3.8, 3.4, 1.8, 2, 2.6, 2.6, 3.4, 3.8, 3.6, 2.8, 
3.2, 3.4, 3.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3, 3.2, 3, 2.4, 3.4, 3.6, 3.6, 3, 3.6, 
4, 2.2, 2.8, 2.8, 3.2, 2.2, 1.6, 3.4)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Where does the `interact_plot` function come from?

Comment: sara, welcome to SO! Regarding the comments above, it's super important too to to list packages, I think `interact_plot` comes from **interactions**, which is not a package I'm familiar with. Might be important to check that function.

Comment: I added the data so it's reproducable.

Comment: Your error isn't reproducible for me; it produces an intersection plot. Are you sure you've called `library(interactions)` and that your packages and R versions are updated?

Comment: i'm going to cry!!!! thanks for your comment!
I checked for updates but everything is in order!

Comment: What version of `interactions` and R are you currently using?

Comment: I use R Studio Version 1.3.1093. When I click "Check for updates" it says there are none.

Comment: Your RStudio version is [likely at least two years old](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/older-versions/), the current version is 2022.07.2. Please update R and RStudio to the most recent version if you can.

Comment: Did updating R and RStudio solve your error message?

Answer (score -1):

First, put your data into a dataframe and run the model:

```
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(rws,efs,ocs))
model1 <- lm(efs ~ ocs * rws, data = data)
```

Next, the `sjPlot` package is very useful in this case.

```
library(sjPlot)
sjPlot::plot_model(model1, type='int')
```

You can also create neat tables with the same package:

```
sjPlot::tab_model(model1)
```